# NestJS mvc + API dynamic rendering

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I just started with NestJS and wanted to know if it is possible to dynamically render a response either as JSON or HBS template based on the header `Accept` value.

I have a backend built using NestJS serving pure REST APIs, now I also want to render `HBS` templates for the same controller methods. Something like the following, but with a better, cleaner approach.

```js
@Get()
async getAll(@Headers() headers, @Res() res: Response): Promise<Pattern[]> {
  const products = await this.productsService.getAll();
  if(headers.accept === "accept/json"){
    return products;
  }
  return res.render(
    this.appService.getViewName(),
    { products },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it with ternary operator:

```js
const products = await this.productsService.getAll();
return headers.accept === "accept/json" ? products : res.render(this.appService.getViewName(), {products});
```

Comment: thats not a cleaner solution, assume your entire projects controller methods last line is `if else ternary operator` condition.

Comment: @nick I misunderstood your question then. You can probably create a builder for that, and then pass it whatever you need. You have an example of builder pattern in JS here -> https://zetcode.com/javascript/builderpattern/